# Paginaçao com EF 7 Asp.net 5 MSQL 2008

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Bom dia gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma solução para paginação usando `EF - Entity Framework` para versões anteriores ao `MSQL 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o [PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/).

Recomendo também instalar o [PagedList.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.EntityFramework/) para suporte a operações assíncronas.